# How to solve this coupled linear differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

$\partial_t f(x,t)= \alpha \partial_x^2f+\beta f + \gamma g \\ \partial_t g(x,t)= \alpha \partial_x^2g -\beta f - \gamma g$

With everything real.

I tried to take the first equation and express g(x,t) as function of f(x,t)

$g=\frac{1}{\gamma}\partial_t f-\alpha \partial_x^2f-\beta f$

and substitute g in the second expression. Then trying to solve with Fourier transform doesn't seem to work.

Or adding both equation leads to

$\partial_t(f+g)=\alpha\partial_x^2(f+g)$.

Assuming variables can be separated for (f+g) this can be solved for (f+g) like a wave propagation equation. But anyway this does not solve the problem.

Thanks for indications.

Comment: maybe define $f+g=u$. Then you obtain the heat in terms of $u$, which is easy to solve. Now choose one of the other equations and replace e.g. in the first equation $g=u-f$. which becomes then a linear parabolic differential equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce the new unknown functions
$$u:=\beta f+\gamma g,\qquad s:=f+g\ .$$
Then the system gets decoupled:
$$u_t=\alpha u_{xx}+(\beta-\gamma) u,\qquad s_t=\alpha s_{xx}\ .$$
Maybe there will be difficulties when $\beta=\gamma$; see Juan Ospina's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Fourier transform and Maple I am obtaining

[image]

I am using the initial conditions

$$f \left( x,0 \right) =a{\it Dirac} \left( x \right)$$

$$g \left( x,0 \right) =b{\it Dirac} \left( x \right)$$